# How to make the background resize only horizontally on different screen sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like my background to respond just horizontally to screen size changes, I don't want the grey frame around it.

CSS of the div:

```
.col-xs-8.arrow-red {
    background-image: url(../img/arrow-red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;                 
    background-position: center center;
    height: 135px;
}
```

This is on desktop:
[image]
Here it is on iPad:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed height for background;
Use like this-

```
-o-background-size:100% 50px;
-webkit-background-size:100% 50px;
-moz-background-size:100% 50px;
background-size:100% 50px;
```

[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size)